# a java generic programming question

Tags: java

I have a class A like this:

```
public class A<T extends Number>
{
 ....
}
```

In another class I have this method:

```
public Hashtable<String, A> createAHashtable()
    {
        Hashtable<String, A> hTable = new Hashtable<String, A>();

        return hTable;
    }
```

There is a warning for parameter A because it is generic class. So should I do this:

```
public Hashtable<String, A <?>> createAHashtable()
        {
            Hashtable<String, A<?>> hTable = new Hashtable<String, A<?>>();

            return hTable;
        }
```

or do this:

```
public Hashtable<String, A <? extends Number>> createAHashtable()
{
Hashtable<String, A<? extends Number> hTable = new Hashtable<String, A<? extends Number>();

return hTable;
}
```

or ....???

**EDIT:**

Tried this (as suggested by Dilum)

```
public <T extends Number> Hashtable<String, A<T>> createAHashtable()
    {
        Hashtable<String, A<T>> hTable = 
                new Hashtable<String, A<T>>();
        A<Float> constraint = new A<Float>();
        hTable.put("test", constraint);

        return hTable;
    }
```

But it is invalid to "put" my Float A.

Maybe the wildcard is the way to go.

**EDIT 2:**

Based on Dilum's suggestion, the following code (cast to A when put a Float A into the Hashtable) has no error but warning it is unsafe cast. Why we need the cast?

```
public <T extends Number> Hashtable<String, A<T>> createAHashtable()
        {
            Hashtable<String, A<T>> hTable = 
                    new Hashtable<String, A<T>>();
            A<Float> constraint = new A<Float>();
            hTable.put("test", (A<T>)constraint);

            return hTable;
        }
```

Comment: As far as I can tell they both should be fine. :-)

Comment: Except that nowhere is a generic argument ever properly supplied to `A`. He's just got wildcards everywhere.

Comment: Edit2 is not good code. Here's why: there are three possible scenarios. Case 1 -  all callers to `createAHashtable` are capable of handling values of `A<T>` AND `A<Float>`. This is difficult to model in Java without an additional indirection. Case 2 -- all callers are capable of handling any `A<Number>`. If so, the API should return `Hashtable<String,A<Number>>`. Case 3 -- A caller expects something other than `A<Float>`, and dies with a class cast exception at runtime.

Comment: So, generic is not the same as inheritance.  we cannot mix Float, Long and Integer together and put them into one collection container.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
public <T extends Number> Hashtable<String, A<T>> createAHashtable() {
  return new Hashtable<String, A<T>>();
}
```

Say you did want to pre-fill with a key-value pair, try:

```
public <T extends Number> Hashtable<String, A<T>> createAHashtableWithEntry(String key, T value) {
  Hashtable<String, A<T>> ht = return new Hashtable<String, A<T>>();
  ht.put(key, new A<T>(value));
  return ht;
}
```

Comment: An `A<T>` is not always an `A<Float>`. So you cannot add it.

Comment: why we need the cast? that means <? extends Number> may be a better solution?

Comment: What do you mean cast? I didn't write any casts. I have a suspicion what you are looking for is just `Hashtable<String, A<Number>)`

Comment: Please look at my edit 2, the A class is a T extends Number generic class, so I plan to add Float A object, Integer A object and Long A object into that Hashtable within that createAHashtable() method.

Answer (score 0):

Related to edit 2:

Here's a concrete example of why the case is unsafe.  On my IDE I actually don't even get a warning that the cast is unsafe.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Genericss {

   static <T extends Number> List<A<T>> get2() {
      List<A<T>> list = new ArrayList<A<T>>();
      A<Float> f = new A<Float>(3.0f);
      list.add((A<T>) f); // Compiles... not even a warning on my IDE
      return list;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      List<A<Integer>> l = Genericss.<Integer>get2();
      Integer i = l.get(0).get(); // runtime error

      A<Float> f = new A<Float>(3f);
      //i = (A<Integer>) f;  // won't compile
   }

   public static class A<T> {
      T t;

      public A(T t) {
         this.t = t;
      }

      public T get() {
         return t;
      }
   }
}
```